# Rails quiz app, chain of questions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im trying to build rails quiz app. And the feature and problem is make a chain of questions where answer on current question is a key to show next question. And all it should display on one page without reloading. The scheme of this logic is next. 
I have table Game:

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :game_block, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :game_block,
end
```

and table GameBlock:

```
class GameBlock < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :game
end
```

GameBlock contain question and key.
Now I only can show all game blocks which belongs to game on games page. The question is how can I realise such feature when user open game page, there is avaible only first game block and input field with button. When user enter some text in this field and press the button this text will compare with field "key" of this game block record. And if they are similar next block will be displayed. Otherwise it will show some flash like "incorrect answer".
The main problem is I cant use js frameworks like React or other.

Comment: It sounds like you'll be wanting to make AJAX requests to populate your data. You can do this in vanilla javascript:  https://www.sitepoint.com/guide-vanilla-ajax-without-jquery/

Comment: @0112 Yeah, seems good. Now I need just understand how to realize it. And when I told about no js frameworks I mean a huge libs like React or Angular. Jquery will be fine. Thanks!